# Is it right to use "throughout" with yesterday or today?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Are these expressions correct?

1: Throughout yesterday afternoon, the place was noisy because of the event.

2: It was very cold and freezing throughout yesterday.

Comment: The first sounds pretty strange and the second sounds very strange, perhaps even wrong. Some people might regard them both as grammatical but native speakers wouldn't use either.

Answer (score 9):

Both are grammatical, but they are not necessarily what a native speaker would say. In the case of the first you might be just as likely to hear *All yesterday afternoon . . .* In the case of the second, *all day  yesterday* might be more common.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Barry's suggestions, I would put forth *all through yesterday afternoon* or *throughout the day yesterday* as likely options.