# Why isn't it natural to say "throughout today" or "throughout yesterday"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrases, idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context

### Question

According to [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/997/is-it-right-to-use-throughout-with-yesterday-or-today), the following uses of *throughout* are grammatical, but sound strange to native speakers(or maybe even wrong according to a comment on the post):

- *throughout today*
- *throughout yesterday*

I have two questions that the post didn't give an answer to:

1. Why using *today* and *yesterday* right after *throughout* make the phrase sound strange, while using other words (e.g.: *the day*, *an entire day*, *her life*, etc.) does not.
2. Are there any other words than *today* and *yesterday* that make the phrase sound strange when used right after *throughout*?

### My speculation

#### For the question 1

I speculate the answer to the question 1 is potentially the following:

- Using *today* or *yesterday* is confusing because they're often used as an adverb, as opposed to a noun, which should be used right after the preposition *throughout*. By the way, *throughout* can also be used as an adverb, which further complicates things.

But I'm not sure this is an enough reason why native speakers feel a relatively strong sense of strangeness (or even wrongness).

#### For the question 2

I speculate *tomorrow* is also make the phrase sound strange because of its similar use to *today* and *yesterday*, but other than that I don't have any clue.

### *throughout* example phrases

The following phrases are collected from the web. I'm assuming these uses are grammatical and sound natural.

> In most cases, they need to have hay or pasture **throughout the day**, with additional grain feedings twice a day.
>
> https://www.humanesociety.org/resources/horse-care-guidelines

> : lasting for, occupying, or appearing **throughout an entire day**
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-day

> The museum is open daily **throughout the year**.
>
> https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/throughout?q=throughout

> The national tragedy of rival groups killing each other continued **throughout 1990**.
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throughout

> troubled her **throughout her life**
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throughout

> Movie music can be made memorable because its themes are repeated **throughout the film.**
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throughout

> Heavy snow will keep falling **throughout the day today**, forecasts Environment Canada.
>
> https://www.nanaimobulletin.com/news/more-snow-in-the-forecast-in-nanaimo/

Comment: For me, "throughout the day" and "throughout the day today/yesterday/tomorrow" feel more idiomatic than "throughout today/yesterday/tomorrow". I don't know of a deeper reason than one phrasing being more common than another. [Some Google n-gram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throughout+today%2Cthroughout+yesterday%2Cthroughout+tomorrow%2Cthroughout+the+day+today%2Cthroughout+the+day+yesterday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @nschneid Thank you for mentioning the phrase "throughout the day today". I think it's good one so I've edited my post and added it to examples. Also, the Google Ngram link is insightful. Some book use "throughout today", so it's normal than I thought? You can check those books by clicking ">" on the page. Although, I understand that the high occurrence of the phrase is because it's often combined with other words, as in "throughout today's world", etc.

Comment: _An operation involving both Neighbourhood Policing and Crime Ops took place **throughout yesterday** after police received intelligence about a suspected cannabis factory._ Gloucestershire (UK) Constabulary, 2021

Comment: _**Throughout tomorrow**, 2 March, some schools may be affected by ongoing strikes by the National Education Union._ also _The forecast is similar in Poole, with rain and cold temperatures expected **throughout tomorrow.**_ also _Shrewsbury incident safely concluded. West Mercia Police news 9 Dec 2022 — Reassurance patrols will continue **throughout tomorrow**. If any member of the public has any concerns please speak to one of our officers._

Comment: You frequently hear **"throughout yesterday / today / tomorrow / the day"** used in radio and TV weather forecasts.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to speak about things happening *on* a specific date, for example "*it's taking place on the 5th of January*" or "*on Wednesday*".

By contrast, a nonspecific "day" is just a unit of time, like an hour or a week etc. It means something different to say an event is happening *on* an hour - namely that it will occur precisely as the hour strikes.

When we speak about things happening "*throughout*" a period, we mean a *period* of time rather than a specific *point* in time. So it is idiomatic to say "*throughout the day*" but not a specific date or day.

Also consider that when you speak about things happening 'throughout' a period, you are grouping those things together as if they are a noteworthy collective rather than isolated incidents. For example, if I said "*yesterday I went to a festival, and there were musical acts throughout the day*" you would understand that the festival was a single event that happened on a specific day (yesterday) but that it comprised of individual musical acts happening throughout. They are different ways of referring to time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. For the line: _When we speak about things happening "throughout" a period, we mean a period of time rather than a specific point in time._ What you implied were 1. _throughout_ should be used with `a period of time`, not `a specific point in time`. 2. _today_ and _yesterday_ are `a specific point in time`, not `a period of time`. 3. Since the points made by 1 and 2, _throughout today_ and _throughout yesterday_ are not idiomatic. Did I get your point right?